Copy PDF file in to excel file
Sub CopyAllPDFsFromFolderToExcel()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim pdfFile As String
    Dim pdfFiles As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    folderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Testtt\"
    
    Set pdfFiles = New Collection
    
    pdfFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.pdf")
    

    Do While pdfFile <> ""
        pdfFiles.Add folderPath & pdfFile
        pdfFile = Dir
    Loop

    For i = 1 To pdfFiles.Count

        Shell "C:\Users\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --new-window """ & pdfFiles(i) & """", vbNormalFocus
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        SendKeys "^a", True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        SendKeys "^c", True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        AppActivate Application.Caption
        
        ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Paste
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Range("A1").Select
    Next i

    MsgBox "All PDFs copied!"
End Sub

Here my code. My problem is:
 SendKeys "^c", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

Is not working. Maybe you can help me.
I need to copy multiple PDF to Excel file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your code seems to be attempting to open a PDF in Google Chrome, then send keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+A (Select all) - Ctrl+C (Copy to Clipboard) and paste the result into an Excel Worksheet at Offset 1,0
If you really want to do PDF to Excel conversion over such tricks, you should look at AutoIT.
But the better way would be to extract text from the PDF in a structured way using a text-content extractor library like Poppler and parse the results, then create a proper Excel file.
